# Java txt parser

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to write a java program that will open a .txt file which will contain paragraphs of text. I then want to parse out specific sentences to a file. Specifically "Should have statements. For example:

Test.txt

> Hello all. Here is a a packing list. You should have a toothbrush. You
>   should have a Phone charger. And you definitely should have your
>   wallet.

Goal output:

> Should have a toothbrush. Should have a phone charger. Should have
>   your wallet.

Right now I have the file chooser working correctly. For now I am just trying to break up the individual sentences, then I can go back through and add the "should have logic". right now program is recognizing different sentences, but just keeps reprinting the complete paragraph. Any help walking me through this would be much appreciated.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class PickAFile {
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        try {
            System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +      chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            File file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());

            input = new Scanner(file);

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String message = input.nextLine();
                String[] sentences = message.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s* ");
                for (String s : sentences) {
                    System.out.println(message);
                }
            }

            input.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Output:

> You chose to open this file: test.txt Hello all. Here is a a packing
>   list. You should have a toothbrush. You should have a Phone charger.
>   And you definitely should have your wallet.
>
> Hello all. Here is a a packing list. You should have a toothbrush. You
>   should have a Phone charger. And you definitely should have your
>   wallet.
>
> Hello all. Here is a a packing list. You should have a toothbrush. You
>   should have a Phone charger. And you definitely should have your
>   wallet.
>
> Hello all. Here is a a packing list. You should have a toothbrush. You
>   should have a Phone charger. And you definitely should have your
>   wallet.
>
> Hello all. Here is a a packing list. You should have a toothbrush. You
>   should have a Phone charger. And you definitely should have your
>   wallet.

Comment: In the for loop, did you mean to say System.out.println(s); ??

Comment: Yes I did, Carl. Thanks alot! Helped me move forward. Now individual sentences are being parsed.

Comment: a few pointers : 1) `Scanner` and its `next()` method would help iterate over the words. You could remember the two last words while iterating over them and display them along with the current word when they are "should" and "have" ; 2) regex : it could search for the pattern "should have <word>" ; 3) NLP : if you really want something solid that will work with edge cases such as the "definitely" one, you will need Natural Language Processing. There are libraries handling that, but even then it's going to be a much more complicated solution than the two previous ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String message = input.nextLine();
            String[] sentences = message.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s* ");
            List<String> shouldHaves = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String s : sentences) {
                  if (s.contains("should have"))
                    shouldHaves.add(s);
                }
                for (String s : shouldHaves) {
                  System.out.println(s);
                }
        }
```

Comment: @NotTheDroids Please review, [what should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)